# Gradient color in CSS with percentage

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have only basic knowledge on the CSS. I'm trying to give gradient color for one of my ITEM as per below guidelines and the gradient should be vertical.

[image]

I tried the below , but only the first color is coming all over the region. I dont understand that 30% and 50%. How to achieve this?

```
 .myheader {  
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #mycolor1 85%, #mycolor2 45%, #mycolor3 10%);       
  }
```

Comment: Not sure where you go those numbers from but `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, red);` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eveyrone is giving the `to bottom` solution but the trivial solution is to consider `to top` and keep the percentage values you are using in the picture:

```
linear-gradient(to top, #mycolor3 10%, #mycolor2 45%, #mycolor1 85%);
```

example:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 10%, purple 45%, blue 85%);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Concerning the percentage between (50% and 30%), they are *probably* the color hints (also called color interpolation hints). From [the new specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#color-stop-syntax)

> Between two color stops there can be a **color interpolation hint**, which specifies how the colors of the two color stops on either side should be interpolated in the space between them (by default, they interpolate linearly). There can only be at most one color interpolation hint between any two given color stops; using more than that makes the function invalid.

example:

```css
body {
  background: 
   /* First gradient with hints*/
   linear-gradient(to top, red 10%, purple 45%, blue 85%) left /45% 100%,
   /* Second gradient with hints*/
   linear-gradient(to top, red 10%,27.5% ,purple 45%, 57% ,blue 85%) right/45% 100%;
  
  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Great Explanation! And Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt on those mysterious percentages :)

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy welcome ;) as a side note, where did you get that tools to create gradient? I would like to try it and make sure what I said is correct by setting different values ... the color hint part may be more tricky than this

Comment: Oops i don't know :( . That was mentioned in my company's design document. I took screenshot and gave here. I'm just following those documents to design my application accordingly.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy ok, so only the company knows the real meaning of those extra percentage. There is a high chance they are the color hints but probably not

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the points in ascending order. Just invert the values you have (you don't really need the purple but could add it if desired):

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 15%, red 90%) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I would also like to know about those 30% and 50% mentioned in the picture? Is it something i need to worry or not needed?

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .myheader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 15%, purple 45%, red 90%);       
 }
```

```html
<div class="myheader"></div>
```

The `to bottom` direction tells you that your gradient is going from top to bottom. So if the first color is 85%, that means that it goes down to 85% of the height of the container.

By inverting the percentage (85% -> 15%), you can achieve the result you want.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks . Do you happen to know about that 30% and 50% mentioned in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example , use your rgba colors.

```
.myheader {  
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The percent values must ascend in order. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient )

```
$mycolor1: blue;
$mycolor2: purple;
$mycolor3: red;

.myheader {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $mycolor1 0%, $mycolor2 50%, $mycolor3 90%);
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qa1kLmfc/3/

For your gradient you probably could use just blue and red.

Answer (score 0):

check my practicing code while learning linear-gradient

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
        /*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Using_CSS_gradients*/

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100vh;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .wraper {
            gap: 10px;
            display: flex;
        }

        .box {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .box1 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                lime 0%,
                lime 20%,
                red 30%,
                red 45%,
                cyan 55%,
                cyan 70%,
                yellow 80%,
                yellow 100%
            );
        }

        .box2 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                lime 20%,
                red 30%,
                red 45%,
                cyan 55%,
                cyan 70%,
                yellow 80%
            );
        }

        .box3 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                lime 20%,
                red 30% 45%,
                cyan 55% 70%,
                yellow 80%
            );
        }

        .box4 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                lime 25%,
                red 25%,
                red 50%,
                cyan 50%,
                cyan 75%,
                yellow 75%
            );
        }

        .box5 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                lime 25%,
                red 25% 50%,
                cyan 50% 75%,
                yellow 75%
            );
        );
        }

        .box6 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                lime 0% 25%,
                red 25% 50%,
                cyan 50% 75%,
                yellow 75% 100%
            );
        }

        .box7 {
            background: linear-gradient(red, cyan);
        }

        .box8 {
            background: linear-gradient(red, 20%, cyan);
        }

        .box9 {
            background: linear-gradient(TO LEFT,red, 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }

        .box10 {
            background: linear-gradient(TO RIGHT,red 50%, blue 50%);
        }

        .box11 {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, mistyrose),
            url("https://live.mdnplay.dev/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Using_CSS_gradients/critters.png");
            /*width: 310px;*/
        }

        .box12 {
            background: linear-gradient(
                217deg,
                rgb(255 0 0 / 80%),
                rgb(255 0 0 / 0%) 70.71%
            ), linear-gradient(127deg, rgb(0 255 0 / 80%), rgb(0 255 0 / 0%) 70.71%),
            linear-gradient(336deg, rgb(0 0 255 / 80%), rgb(0 0 255 / 0%) 70.71%);
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="container">
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="box box1"></div>
        <div class="box box2"></div>
        <div class="box box3"></div>
        <div class="box box4"></div>
        <div class="box box5"></div>
        <div class="box box6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="box box7"></div>
        <div class="box box8"></div>
        <div class="box box9"></div>
        <div class="box box10"></div>
        <div class="box box11"></div>
        <div class="box box12"></div>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```